# App-Release.apk not working but App-Debug working?

Tags: android

I have generated a signed apk, with the same keystore, key alias etc. as I always do, but for some reason - the last version does not work properly on most devices. It is way slower and does not implement `IOUtils.toString` properly. Whereas the app-debug is working perfectly.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Are you using proguard rules?

Comment: Yes, I added "dontwatrn" rules to be able to generate the signed apk, why?

Comment: As proguard rules optimises the code and removes unused files so may be because of that you are facing this issue. So probably you have to add proguard rules for that.

Comment: Let me try to use "keep" as well as "dontwarn" and update back.

Comment: No it's not working...